# Cannot install any packages with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try and install any packages with pip I get the following error:

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sendgrid==4.2.0 (from versions: )`

for the sake of an example:

```
pip search sendgrid
> ...
> sendgrid (4.2.0)                   - SendGrid library for Python
> ...

pip install sendgrid
> Collecting sendgrid
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sendgrid (from versions: )
> No matching distribution found for sendgrid
```

Similarly:

```
pip search vcr
>amivcrm (0.1)              - A simple connector to the AMIV SugarCRM
>betamax-matchers (0.4.0)   - A VCR imitation for python-requests
>betamax (0.8.0)            - A VCR imitation for python-requests
>cubicweb-vcrs (0.2.1)      - vcreview statistics
>cubicweb-vcreview (2.4.0)  - patch review system on top of vcsfile
>devcron (0.4)              - Cron for working on projects that use 
>crontabs.
>httpsrvvcr (0.1.9)         - VCR recording proxy-server for usage with 
>vcr (0.0.9)                - VCR - decorator for capturing and simulating network communication
>vcrpy (1.11.1)             - Automatically mock your HTTP interactions to simplify and speed up
                         testing

pip install vcr==0.0.9
>Collecting vcr==0.0.9
>Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vcr==0.0.9 (from versions: )
>No matching distribution found for vcr==0.0.9
```

Running python 3.6 in a virtualenv
mac osx Sierra 10.12.5 (16F2073)

```
which pip
>pip: aliased to noglob pip
```

Comment: Paste the output of `pip search -vvv sendgrid`

Comment: version the pip?

Comment: pip -V: pip 9.0.1 from .../lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

Answer (score 2):

Running the command:

```
pip install sendgrid --isolated
```

Works